# Isotope Filter According To Checkbox State

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

If any of you good folk could cast an eye over this and let me know the error of my ways, that would be fab, cheers!

I'm using isotope to filter items. Each item has the option for users to 'favourite' them.

I can successfully toggle a checkbox and save its current state to localStorage but what I'd like to be able to do is have one of the filter buttons work so it filters (via isotope) any items that have been 'favourited'.

Here are the filter buttons, which all work fine except for the 'favourites'.

HTML

```
<div id="filters" class="button-group">
<button class="button uppercase is-checked" data-filter="*">All</button>
<button class="button uppercase" data-filter=".amber">AMBER</button>
<button class="button uppercase" data-filter=".dark">DARK</button>
<button class="button uppercase" data-filter=".golden">GOLDEN</button>
<button class="button uppercase" data-filter=".ruby">RUBY</button>

<button class="button uppercase" id="checkbox" data-filter=".checkbox">FAVOURITES</button>
</div>
```

And here's the script that I'm trying to make work.

JS

```
function customCheckbox(){
        var checkBox = $('.checkbox');

        //on load select if necessary
        checkBox.each(function(){            
            var id=$(this).data('id');
            if(localStorage.getItem(id)==1){
                $(this).addClass("selected");
            }
        });

        //on click toggle selected and save in localstorage
        checkBox.click(function(){
            var id=$(this).data('id');
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
            if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
                localStorage.setItem(id,1);
            }else{
                localStorage.removeItem(id);
            }
        });
    }


    $(document).ready(function (){
        //start checkboxes here
        customCheckbox();

        //filter button
        var $grid = $('#grid');
        $grid.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.element-item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        transitionDuration: '0.6s'
    });

    $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {           
            $('.checkbox:not(.selected)').parent().show(); 
            $grid.isotope(); //show all not starred blocks
        });

    $('#checkbox').on( 'click', 'button', function(){ 

            $('.checkbox:not(.selected)').parent().hide(); 
            $grid.isotope(); //hide all not starred blocks

        });
```

If anyone can shed any light on where I'm going wrong, it'd be hugely appreciated! Many thanks, in advance, for any help or advice.

UPDATE: I've now created a jsfiddle. I'm new to jsfiddle; so do shout up if I've done it wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/Frannie/rtkpws48/55/

For some reason I can't seem to get the (previously successful) localStorage toggle state of the favourite checkbox to work properly in the fiddle. No idea where I've gone astray???

Anyway, if anyone has any clues as to how to get any of it to work, that would be brilliant!

Comment: Could you please post the html fully ( with class name checkbox) or in jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: Will do, Tamil... two seconds...

Comment: Okay, I am so sorry for the lengthy delay in replying. I haven't used jsfiddle before; so it took a little time to set it up.

https://jsfiddle.net/Frannie/rtkpws48/55/

If I haven't presented anything correctly do please let me know :)

Again, thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try these https://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/rtkpws48/56/

Comment: Tamil you are a total **SUPERSTAR**!!! Your solution is **perfect**. Thank you so, so much! And to @KScandrett, too, for having a look at it for me. I really cannot thank you both enough! It's so kind of you to have taken the time to help me out. Cheeeeeeeeeeeers! x x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When the page loaded, in each checkbox which is localstorage add the class `.checkbox` to the parent div as

   $(this).closest(".element-item").addClass("checkbox");
2. Then when you click favorite, add the class `.checkbox` to parent and when unfavorite remove the class `.checkbox` from the parent.

see: https://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/rtkpws48/56/

Try

```
checkBox.each(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        if (localStorage.getItem(id) == 1) {
            $(this).addClass("selected");

            // add the class checkbox to the parent div
            $(this).closest(".element-item").addClass("checkbox");
        }
    });

    //on click toggle selected and save in localstorage
    checkBox.click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            localStorage.setItem(id, 1);

            // add the class checkbox to the parent div
            $(this).closest(".element-item").addClass("checkbox");
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem(id);
            // remove the class checkbox in parent div
            $(this).closest(".element-item").removeClass("checkbox");
        }
    });
```

*Edit: *

```
$('#filters').on('click', 'button', function() {
    buttonFilter = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    console.log(filterValue);
    $grid.isotope();
    // if filter value is all (*) then
    // empty the search field value
    // and manually trigger keyup
    if( filterValue == '*' ) {
        $('#quicksearch').val('');
        $('#quicksearch').trigger('keyup');
        $grid.isotope();
    }

});
```

Comment: Tamil you are a total **SUPERSTAR**!!!

Your solution is **perfect**. Thank you so, so much!

And to @KScandrett, too, for having a look at it for me.

I really cannot thank you both enough! It's so kind of you to have taken the time to help me out.

Cheeeeeeeeeeeers! x x

Comment: Just one more question... is it possible to make the 'show all' button clear any text that has been typed in the search field? It would be great if there was a way to ensure that when 'show all' is clicked that all items are displayed rather than just whatever still happens to be typed in the search field.

Comment: Awesome! A million thanks, Tamil. Your help really is very gratefully received! :)

Answer (score 0):

The toggle state is not storing because `data-id` is sitting on the wrong element for this selector to populate the variable:

```
      var checkBox = $('.checkbox');
      checkBox.each(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
```

It will work if you move the data-id from the `<i>` to the `<div>` like this:

```
<div class="checkbox" data-id="03"><i style="font-size: 20px;" class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

EDIT

OK, I see how this works. To fix the Favourites problem what you should do in my opinion is move the 'selected' class, from the div with the checkbox class, up to the its parent div. Then the Isotope filter should pick it up automatically as it filters the parent div by its classes. Eg.

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" class="element-item amber selected">
    <h3 class="name">Amber</h3>
    <div class="checkbox" data-id="01"><i style="font-size: 20px;" class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  </div>
```

You will need to update the various jQuery selectors for ".checkbox" to suit , but then filtering by clicking the Favourites should be automatic without needing that 'filter_pinned' code.

And you'll need to change .checkbox to .selected on Favourites

```
<button class="button" data-filter=".selected">Favourites</button>
```